# Comparing CDI and AspectJ

Tags: aop, cdi

We are trying to evaluate CDI and AspectJ in our project. Has someone here done something similar? Can some one share their views on using CDI or AspectJ on some topics like
1. Learning Curve
2. Portability to different servers
3. Maintainability
4. Debuging

Thanks

Answer (score 5):

These are actually very different technologies. CDI is a dependency injection stack (like Spring or Guice) with some AOP features (sufficient in typical use cases). AspectJ is a full-blown aspect-oriented programming *language* that doesn't really offer any dependency-injection features.

> .1. Learning Curve

Both technologies have lots of materials. CDI is new but there is a lot of buzz around it. E.g. see [CDI AOP Tutorial: Java Standard Method Interception Tutorial](http://java.dzone.com/articles/cdi-aop).

AspectJ is much older and there are few fantastic books about it. But I would say it is a bit more demanding.

> .2. Portability to different servers

CDI is a Java standard for DI. We will see more and more servers implementing it. AspectJ is a language that works on a bytecode level. It should work on virtually any JVM (mobile, desktop, server, applet...)

As for maintainability and debugging - these are really different technologies so I won't dive into comparing them here. However CDI is a standard Java code while AspectJ is mostly code-generation at bytecode level. On the other hand AspectJ generated code (stack-traces, decompiling) might be more readable than tons of reflective proxies and CGLIB generated classes with CDI.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. Though there are lot of materials available, personally I feel developers will be more comfortable learning CDI, as it mainly deals in Annotation and some configuration using XML, where as AOP wud be bit difficult to learn as syntax of pointcuts can be difficult and hard to read. So Learning Curve I think CDI wins over AOP